# Musixtex, drum notation, special symbol to represent rolls

Tags: fonts, music, musixtex

I need to write some snare music, and I need for the symbol used to define a roll that is illustrated in the picture below as special note with the two diagonal segments.
Any help ? I need to define a new note ?
Many Thanks
Marco

[image: Double stroke roll]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Could you edit your question to include a small compilable example that shows the image without the roll marks that people could play with.

Answer (score 4):

First time that I write a music code: I have seen the manual [`musixdoc.pdf`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/musixtex/musixdoc.pdf), § 18.4.4 pag. 92 named **Tremolos**. I am not able to write the code with this package. The best answer is of the user @Alan Munn.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\setstaffs1{1}             
\generalmeter{\meterfrac{3}{4}}
\startextract
\NOtesp\trrml f\zqlp f\trrmu j\qup j\en
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: See the comment to the best answer of @Alan Munn.

Comment: Sebastiano, thanks this a very good help, I try to implement the use of tremolos but when I compile I have undefined control sequence errors, I suppose generated by the \trrml ....

Answer (score 2):

As Sebastiano notes in his answer, the tremolo symbol is the same symbol used for roll in percussion notation, so you can use the various tremolo commands to add them to notes. To make the markup more semantic, I've `\let` them to be `\roll`, but this is really just personal preference.

You can add a roll to the first note of a barred pair using the shorthand notation, (first example of bar 1) but if you want to add it to the second note you need to do the bar manually (second example of bar 1). Downward staves will require a manual offset, (bar 2) but since I suspect you can't roll with your feet, this may not be a problem.  Your specific example is given in bar 3.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input{musixper} % percussion additions (percussion note heads, etc.)
\makeatletter
\let\rollu\trrmu % semantic markup 
\let\rolll\trrml %
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\nobarnumbers
\instrumentnumber{1}
   \generalmeter{\meterfrac24}
     \setclefsymbol1\drumclef
     \startextract
     \parindent0pt
     \Notes    \rollu f\Dqbu ff \en % can be used on the first of a auto barred note pair
     \Notes \ibu{1}{f}{0}\qb{1}{f}\rollu f\tqh{1}{f}\en\bar % to get on the second, you need to the bar manually
     \Notes \roffset{.5}{\rolll j} \Dqbl jj \qp\en\bar % downward staves will need some offset but probably not needed
     \Notes \ibu{2}{f}{0}\islurd{2}{f}\zcn{-5}{R}\zcn{10}{5}\rollu f\qb{2}{f}\tslur{2}{f}\zcn{-5}{R}\zcn{10}{$>$}\tqh{2}{f}%
     \ibu{2}{f}{0}\islurd{2}{f}\zcn{-5}{L}\zcn{10}{5}\rollu f\qb{2}{f}\tslur{2}{f}\zcn{-5}{L}\zcn{10}{$>$}\tqh{2}{f}\en
     \endextract
   \end{music}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Excellent. I play the guitar (I am amatorial singer and musicist) :-) but I not play the drum :) that I like very much. I know the notes and the pause :-)

Comment: Thanks Allan, this a very good help, I try to implement the use of tremolos but when I compile I have undefined control sequence errors, I suppose generated by the \trrml .....in the pdf file the notes are good but the two tremolo symbols are not correctly generated

Comment: @MARKREX What is the exact error you get?

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
l.9 \NOtesp\trrml
                  f\zqlp f\trrmu j\qup j\en

Comment: Alan, I reinstallde Miktex just a couple of minutes ago and the problem is always the same Marco

Comment: @MARKREX What version of `musixtex` does the console display when you compile? The tremolo commands were introduced in v 1.19.  You should see a line that looks like `MusiXTeX(c) 1.29 <2018-08-04>` (which is what I'm using).

Comment: In the console I see two lines: musixtex T.103<8 July 2001> and a second line musixlatex T.125<8 april 2017> If I check on the administration tool on the Miktex console the package info shows  1.30

Comment: @MARKREX `T.103` shouldn't be there. It looks like you have an old local version of `musixtex` in your local `texmf` folder.  The console output should also show the full path of the file being loaded. Can you say what that shows.

Comment: Alan, this morning I check for this file and I found an old version of musixtex in the same directory of the files I am compiling, I deleted these files and now anything works well, great suggestion ....many thanks Alan !

Comment: Alan, I have no errors in compiling your code, the only problem I have is that I cannot visualize correctly the  accent symbol ">". I mean no compilation errors  but the accent symbol is visualized like a reversed question mark. Thanks !

Comment: I solved just by using $>$ Many Thanks for all Marco

Answer (score 0):

Percussion code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{musixtex}
\input{musixlyr}
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

\usepackage{pifont} % Para usar simbolos ding
\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \largemusicsize
    \setlines{1}{0}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
    \nobarnumbers
    \nostartrule
    \startextract
    {\Huge{\ding{198}}}$\quad$
    \NOtes \zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small \hspace*{0.16cm} R $\quad\,$ R}
    \zcn{i}{\hspace*{0.25cm}$5$} \ibu0a0\islurd0a\trrmu a\qb0{a}\tbu0\tslur0a\usf f\qb0{a} \en
    \NOtes \zcharnote{-10}{\textbf\small \hspace*{0.16cm} L $\quad\,$ L}
    \zcn{i}{\hspace*{0.25cm}$5$} \ibu0a0\islurd0a\trrmu a\qb0{a}\tbu0\tslur0a\usf f\qb0{a} \en
    \zendextract
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: output]